# mobify.js, Android 2.3, and talkback

Tags: android, accessibility, mobify, mobify-js

Has anyone using mobify.js seen talkback not work, especially on Android 2.3? We know it's not the device as other non-mobify sites work fine. Newer versions of android work fine, just 2.3.

I suspect it's how mobify work that is cause the problem, just i can't confirm.

Cheers.
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [FAQ](http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/android_access/faq.html) the default web browser is not accessible in anything below Android 4.0. Unless you can confirm that 2.2 works with Talkback this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks Jared. We confirmed it's Talk Back. Seems it works at the OS level (UI interactions, icon touch, etc), but nothing within the browser.